# Setting up a Gentoo Repository on a Debian Host

Tags: debian, package-management, gentoo, repository

I have a debian host, on which i want to setup a private Gentoo Repository for my college. I have started syncing the repository by a simple bash script whose snippet is as follows :

```
RSYNC="/usr/bin/rsync"
OPTS="--quiet --recursive --links --perms --times -D --delete --timeout=300"
SRC="rsync://rsync.de.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage"
DST="
```

What else I need to do for setting up the repository?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Gentoo is the answer to very many problems, *especially* this one--

However, if you are already programmatically syncing your portage tree, do you need anything else other than the rsync?

All straight from [the docs](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/rsync.xml#local):

Your shell script, run via cron:

```
RSYNC="/usr/bin/rsync"
OPTS="--quiet --recursive --links --perms --times -D --delete --timeout=300"
SRC="rsync://rsync.de.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage"
DST="/space/gentoo/portage/"

echo "Started update at" `date` >> $0.log 2>&1
logger -t rsync "re-rsyncing the gentoo-portage tree"
${RSYNC} ${OPTS} ${SRC} ${DST} >> $0.log 2>&1
```

In rsyncd.conf:

```
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
max connections = 5
use chroot = yes
uid = nobody
gid = nobody
# Optional: restrict access to your Gentoo boxes
hosts allow = 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.1.0/24
hosts deny  = *

[gentoo-portage]
path=/space/gentoo/portage
comment=Portage tree
```

Then start the rsync daemon like `rsync --daemon`

I haven't tested any of this, but it should get you pretty close...  Unless you want to [install portage right under a non-gentoo distro](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic.php?t=28559)?